DateTime is switching Day and Month
I have a swagger page with an endpoint that has a DateTime as query parameter string($date-time).
All date formats seems to be ok but if I pass this format:
10/12/2024 (Day/Month/Year) it switches Day and Month, when I debug it is set like 12/10/2024.
This format 2024/12/10 is ok.
What am I missing?

The root problem is that 10/12/2024 is ambiguous and can be interpreted as either 10th December or 12th October and unfortunately the default for .NET is the latter (probably because C# and .NET were created by Americans). Sticking to the ISO-8601 standard of yyyy-MM-dd will prevent any issues. Ideally you should use ISO-8601 compatible formats when transmitting any date/time information.

Probably culture related, some cultures have month/day/year, others have day/month/year when representing the date as text.

Similar to the reason devs always mix up Halloween and X-Mas: Dec 25 == Oct 31 :D

2024/12/10 is ok. it's not. The standard way to represent dates in JSON is ISO8601, ie YYYY-MM-DD.  DateTime has no format or parts order, it's a binary value. Internally, time is stored as a single Ticks number that represents 100ns intervals.  Formats apply only when parsing strings into this binary value, or formatting the binary value as a string

The real solution is to discard the invalid strings, ie every string that isn't in ISO8601 format. The duplicate question and the Swagger data types doc show you can specify this by adding format: date or format: date-time to the parameter specification. I'd expect ASP.NET Core to generate this automatically

@Fildor (groan)

@PanagiotisKanavos but in code I use [FromQuery] DateTime? from = null

That doesn't change the fact that there's no way to tell whether 04/07/2024 is July 4th or April 7th. In the US that's April 7th, everywhere else it's July 4th. ASP.NET Core's model binder used the Invariant culture to parse the ambiguous string, which is equivalent to using the US culture. Hard-coding a different culture isn't a solution as all clients will expect ISO8601 strings to work. Instead of guessing, prevent the use of non-standard strings entirely.

@PanagiotisKanavos I understand, but how do I force a specific format? Or just add format documentation in the swagger definition? Adding a Filter?

Did you check the duplicate question? You haven't posted any code or the part of your API's  Swagger definition that deals with this parameter. Does it have format: date? Post the relevant code and spec in the question
